# Return code of sqlite3_exec()

Tags: c++, multithreading, sqlite

First I should mention that I use sqlite3 in a program with several threads. Two threads read only (using SELECT) while one thread only inserts stuff.

I make the insertion using an exec command like this

```
int irc = sqlite3_exec(m_poDB, requestBuffer, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
// requestBuffer contains INSERT statement as a string
```

Sometimes it returns 100 (SQLITE_ROW) and sometimes 101 (SQLITE_DONE), and never 0 (SQLITE_OK). Why? I don't understand how it can return SQLITE_ROW if I insert one record.

For example: `INSERT INTO Labels(Amount, Color) VALUES ('3255','Red')` returns `SQL-Error 100 while Request makeEntry_Label: not an error`.

`INSERT INTO Labels(Amount, Color) VALUES ('3257','Blue')` returns `SQL-Error 101 while Request makeEntry_Label: not an error`

Sometimes, I also get `SQL-Error 100 while Request makeEntry_Label: unknown error`